Can you open the relevant .java file from a .xml layout file in Android Studio?
I'm aware of cmd + click on layout name in .java file.
But is there a way to navigate to the .java file from layout .xml file?

As one layout can be used in multiple Java files this can get difficult to implement such a function. Simply use the the search function and the resource id/name of the XM file.
